# Rewrite all urls in project with wamp and Codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, url-rewriting, wamp

I have my project in `C:/wamp/www/v3`

When I open the project through `http://localhost/v3` I get the default controller as expected.

Now, in my code I have some urls like `<a href="/login"></a>` but when I click I get a not found page because it opens `http://localhost/login` instead of `http://localhost/v3/login`

I've tried virtualhosts and rewritebase with the htaccess but I can't get to redirect to the correct url.

My htaccess located inside /v3/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config for your application (root folder)/application/config.php there is a base_url variable that you can set.  Try setting it to 'http://localhost/v3'.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already did that, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try putting an htaccess file in the C:/wamp/www directory with a rewrite rule like this in it (note - not tested, could need a touch up or two):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v3/
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$     /v3/$1  [R]
```

But this means ALL urls that don't start with /v3/ will be rewritten to have the /v3/ at the beginning.  Really the problem is your URLs start with /, so the browser is doing its job and asking for a url without the /v3 at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your anchor is set to point to `/login` which means `http://mydomain/login`. the starting `/` means "point to webroot".

a quick way to do this (especially when using templates), is to pass the values of `base_url()` and `site_url()` ([from the URL helper class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html))  to your view and prepend your links with them like:

```
<a href="<?= base_url().'/login' ?>">Login</a>
```

or if i pass`$data` to the template with `base_url()` as $data['base_url']:

```
<a href="{base_url}login">Login</a>
```

*Note: `base_url()` and `site_url()` includes a trailing slash*

the effect will give you this (assuming you have not removed "index.php" using rewrite):

```
<a href="http://localhost/v3/index.php/login">Login</a>
```

or if removed, it will return:

```
<a href="http://localhost/v3/login">Login</a>
```

Comment: Yes, the base_url() is a fast solution, but this local site is going to be deployed at the root of our web server.

So I know there must be something to rewrite the urls while I work in my localhost. Typing base_url in all the code is a bit annoying.

Comment: how about adding `v3` when rewriting for index.php, like: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v3/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: yes I did that too, nothing happened :(

(yes, i have mod_rewrite module activated)

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to use site_url('link/to'); on any anchor on my site, it saves me a lot of time when i have to migrate it to another server/folder.

If you don't want to do this, you can use basetag to put a base url for all your links.

In the  tag:

```
<base href="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" />
```

Also, if i'm understand correctly, you already try to put RewriteBase /v3/ in your .htaccess, right?

Regards

Comment: Yes, I added RewriteBase /v3/ and uncommented it.
I don't know why it's not possible just to rewrite all my urls (css, images, anchors) to have the /v3/ at the beginning, without adding the typical base_url() or site_url().